# Delphi win32 application to work with Oracle

Tags: oracle, delphi

I have to create win32 client on Delphi, which can work with database on Oracle. The only problem  with this task that client have to demand "zero administration". 
In other words user downloaded it from our site and ran it without any installing oracle client and tuning tnsnames.ora.

My first aproach was to install apache on server side with connection to Oracle. Our win32 client this case is like web brouser works with Oracle via https.

It works but performance is not so good as expected. Delay in reaction between clent and server side is too long.

Is there any way to acheve my goal (zero adminstration client with good enough performance)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The product ODAC (Oracle Data Access Components) from DevArt has a "no oracle client needed" mode.  This would probably be the easiest solution.  You could also just include the Oracle Instant Client with your product and use Oracle's "EZConnect" syntax so that you don't have to configure anything on the client.  Using EZConnect allows you to connect to an Oracle Database without using a TNSNames.ora file.

Comment: Thank you. Seems very interesing. I didn't know about this option in ODAC component.
I'll try to use it.